# Firebase authentication: linking multiple accounts in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've set up Firebase authentication for my iOS app using Facebook, Google & email/password sign in and it's all working fine. This authentication only happens when the user wants to access high-priority parts of my app (i.e. I don't require users to sign in to start using the app).

On app start up, I sign users in anonymously in the background and that's working fine too.

I've read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking) but I'm struggling to understand the code required to enable me to link an anonymous account to a Facebook/email signed in account in the following flow:

- new user opens app
- user signed in anonymously in the background (new user.uid "A" created)
- low priority data stored against anonymous user in Firebase realtime DB
- user hits a high-priority area so needs to authenticate
- user signs in using Facebook (new user.uid "B" created)
- previous user.uid "A" needs to be linked to user.uid "B"

My method currently looks like this:

```
func signupWithFacebook(){
    // track the anonymous user to link later
    let prevUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

    FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) in
        if let token = result?.token?.tokenString {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(token)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential, completion: { (user, error) in
                if user != nil && error == nil {
                    // Success
                    self.success?(user: user!)
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    })

                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Any pointers to remove the confusion would be great.

---

**UPDATE:**
I've realised I was confused about the app logic because of users being created during testing. Instead of 2 separate users being created for the above scenario (one authenticated via Facebook and another anonymously), all that happens is that the original anonymous user.uid "A" is "linked" to some Facebook authentication credentials. In the Firebase console this is shown by the anonymous uid changing from anonymous to one with the Facebook logo next to it.

This is what my working method looks like:

```
func signupWithFacebook(){
    FBSDKLoginManager().logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], fromViewController: self) { (result, error) in
        if let token = result?.token?.tokenString {
            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(token)

            FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser!.linkWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                if user != nil && error == nil {
                    // Success
                    self.success?(user: user!)
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    })
                } else {
                    print("linkWithCredential error:", error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to use firebase authentication it requires a email/password or facebook/gmail authentication. How are you authenticating anonymously?

Comment: Ok. Read through documentation and they've changed it a bit since I last used firebase. I'll look into it.

Comment: @NSGangster I'm using `FIRAuth.auth()?.signInAnonymouslyWithCompletion()` from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your code follows the first 2 steps in [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) link. But the documentation explicity says not to call `signInWithCredential` but instead call

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
  // ...
}
```

After getting your credential from Facebook's SDK.

Quote from link: `"If the call to linkWithCredential:completion: succeeds, the user's new account can access the anonymous account's Firebase data."`

Comment: Thanks for this. As I mentioned in my Q, I'm confused. I've got myself really muddled because during testing I've created users by authenticating directly with Facebook (without being Anonymous users beforehand). As a result my logic was to have 2 firebase users (facebook & anonymous) for the same person and try to link the two _users_. In actual fact what happens is (as written in your answer/the docs) that you only link the _credentials_ (to the original anonymous user) and there is only ever a single user created. Seems to be clear (and work!) now. Thanks - phew!

Comment: @NSGangster  signInWithCredential is for authenticating the user for the first time and the linkWithCredential is for if the user is already authenticated!  Am I right??

Comment: I don't get when to attempt to linkWithCredential. For example, let's say User A creates an account with email and password. Then he logs out. Then he decides to login with Facebook. Is it possible to link? Or is it only possible to sign a user in using Method A, and then while signed in, link Method B? I'm trying to avoid multiple accounts being created. From a UX perspective, you can't rely on users linking accounts. There has to be a way to account for a user logging out and then signing back in with a new method.

Comment: What will be the uid after linking? Will it be same as anonymous user, or will it change to linked user's id?