# Firebase authentication: handling logging out (and back in) in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to figure out how to allow my app users to log out (and then log back in successfully).

I have an iOS app which uses Firebase Authentication with the following user flow/logic:

1. a new user opens the app
2. they are logged in automatically as an anonymous user (uid-A)
3. sometime later, they want to access something sensitive so...
4. they log in with Facebook and link the credentials with uid-A
5. they want to log out so call `FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()`
6. when the user revisits the app they're issued a new anonymous user (uid-B)
7. they try to log in using Facebook again but...
8. they get an "ERROR_CREDENTIAL_ALREADY_IN_USE" error because their Facebook credentials are linked to uid-A

Has anyone got an app logic which works for this use case? Should I be doing something different at step 5 above (i.e. not actually logging the user out but simply destroying the credentials or something)? Any pointers/ideas would be great.

Comment: How are you linking Facebook with the anonymous user login in step 4?

Comment: I've just solved that and posted the code on SO here (scroll to the bottom of the Q for the updated code block): http://stackoverflow.com/q/38634482/131385

Comment: Probably should check to see if facebook account is linked to a uid, and if it is log out the new anonymous user before logging into with facebook authentication.

Comment: @NSGangster thanks - I was hoping that wasn't going to be the answer as I'll have to reconcile any activity that happened while the user was uid-B with what exists on uid-A at the moment they re-log in. Messy! :-) "downgrading" uid-A would be much slicker. Perhaps unlinking the credentials is designed for this use case...will try it.

Comment: Yeah definitely unlinking credentials is an option. But then facebook user loses any progress they did with uid-A

Comment: @NSGangster I'm thinking perhaps I can use unlinking _instead_ of signing out. So the user is always uid-A but their "status" is back to Anonymous again. Will try it when I'm back at my desk and post code if I get it working.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Although it almost seems unnecessary in most cases to even have FB authentication at that point. Unless of course you will be using FB SDK for accessing friends and that sort of thing.

Comment: @NSGangster I'm using FB so that the user can sync important info across devices/get their info after they upgrade their handset etc. Food for thought though :-)